# Next JS API routes executing imported modules more than once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, node-modules

I have two API routes defined in `pages/api/item/get.ts` and `pages/api/item/set.ts`. Both of these look very similar, importing an instance of a db:

```
import db from "../../../helpers/db";

export default function handler(req, res) {
  //
}
```

The db file sets up an instance of a db connection and exports it. I've added a log to indicate when the module is executed:

```
// helpers/db.ts

const db = new Db()

console.log("Executing module");

export default db;
```

What I've found is that "Executing module" is logged once per API call (at compile time? NextJS logs show that API endpoints get compiled )

```
wait  - compiling /api/item/get...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 103 ms (328 modules)
```

Further repeated calls of either API endpoint do not result in any more logs. IIRC JS modules should only be executed once so this behaviour is unexpected. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this occuring on production mode too? The comments on the official mongodb example indicate that it should not: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js#L13-L25

Comment: This thread might shed some light on that behaviour: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10933#issuecomment-598297975.